# ChromeCast - Not able to display Cast ActionBar Button

Tags: android, chromecast

I am writing my first Google Cast application for Android. Going through sender code posted on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender. The cast button is not showing up in the ActionBar. I used CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID as an APP_ID.

And do I need to register ChromeCast device in Google Console in-order to make it discoverable for android sender applications?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you are using the default media receiver, you do not need to register your device for discovery to happen. Are you using an ActionbarActivity?

Comment: yes, i'm using ActionbarActivity.